# error while checking if boolean value is yes or no in ios uiwebview objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Am trying to check if the URL am loading in IOS UIWebView has error or not, am using the below code to get the request url status code if `200` i will like to set `isRequestWebOk` to `YES` else i will use the default `NO`, everything seems to work well except that `isRequestWebOk` still return `NO` even when status code is 200 and i do set it `if(200){isRequestWebOk = YES;}`.
Please can anyone help me i don't know why is not working properly.

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType{
    static BOOL isRequestWeb = YES;
    static BOOL isRequestWebOk = NO;
    NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head></head><body style='color:#000;'><p>Error</p></body></html>";

    if (isRequestWeb) {
        //NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        //NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:inRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        //if (response.statusCode == 404) {}

        [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:inRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
            if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300){
                /*I think this do set but i can't access it outside the completionHandler but i really need to check it outside as i cannot do many other things inside here*/
                isRequestWebOk = YES;
                NSLog(@"GOOD");
            }else if (statusCode == 404) {
                NSLog(@"code for 404");
            }else if (statusCode == 403) {
                NSLog(@"code for 403");
            }else if (statusCode == 500) {
                NSLog(@"code for 500");
            }else{
                NSLog(@"code for ALL");
                isRequestWebOk = YES;
            }
            NSLog(@"code is what: %ld", (long)statusCode);
        }] resume];
        isRequestWeb = NO;

        /*This is where am checking for isRequestWebOk if true or not but it always return false*/
        if(isRequestWebOk){
            NSLog(@"Request is okay 200");
            return YES;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Bad Request b4004");
            inWeb.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            inWeb.opaque = NO;
            inWeb.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [inWeb loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I think this do set but i can't access it outside the completionHandler but i really need to check it outside as i cannot do many other things inside there

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous programming. When your completion handler is executed, the `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` is already done and your check got already executed with the original value.
The handler is a block that get's copied and executed at a later time, thus asynchronous.

Comment: Also, WebKit asks you if it *should* execute the request. Why do you load the request and then decide wether it should be loaded or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this block of code:

```
if(isRequestWebOk){
    NSLog(@"Request is okay 200");
    return YES;
}else{
    NSLog(@"Bad Request b4004");
    inWeb.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    inWeb.opaque = NO;
    inWeb.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [inWeb loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];
    return NO;
}
```

To inside the `completionHandler`.

At the time you are checking here if `isRequestWebOk` is `YES` or `NO` the request may still be in progress.

Comment: Doing it this way I get warning `Thread 10: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1f25e5508)` and `-[UIWebView setOpaque:] must be used from main thread only`and I have other code I will use inside there that might cause more errors

Comment: You can keep Mo's solution, but simply update the UI elements by dispatching to the main thread.

Comment: The problem is that he wants to decide wether or not to load the data by loading the data and examining the results.